# React formik: how to show error message if email/password is incorrect

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik, yup

I want a form where it returns an error message like email/password incorrect, now nothing shows if I enter wrong credentials .
here is what I have now :

```
`const loginSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().email("invalid email").required("required"),
  password: yup.string().required("required"),
});
...
const initialValuesLogin = {
  email: "",
  password: "",
};
...
```

this is my login function where I tried to test and send the error message but nothing is showing :

```
 const Form = () => {
 const login = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
    const loggedInResponse = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/auth/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(values),
    })
    const loggedIn = await loggedInResponse.json();
    onSubmitProps.resetForm();
   if (loggedIn && loggedIn.error) {
     onSubmitProps.setErrors({ email: "Invalid email or password" });
  } else if (loggedIn) {
    dispatch(
      setLogin({
        user: loggedIn.user,
        token: loggedIn.token,
      })
    );
      navigate("/home");
    }
  };
  }
```

This is the formik, I have later on the textfields for both email and password , they do show an error if not filled since its required or email format incorrect

```
  return (
    <Formik
      onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
      initialValues={isLogin ? initialValuesLogin : initialValuesRegister}
      validationSchema={isLogin ? loginSchema : registerSchema}
    >
```

This is the server side code :

```
    export const login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "User does not exist. " });

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Invalid credentials. " });

    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    delete user.password;
    res.status(200).json({ token, user });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with formik but to axios error handling. You should update your call function to use a **try catch block** then check if the error code is 400 (for invalid credentials)

```
const login = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
 try {
    const loggedInResponse = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/auth/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(values),
    })
    const loggedIn = await loggedInResponse.json();
    onSubmitProps.resetForm();
    // make sure you have a token
    if(loggedIn.token) {
      dispatch( setLogin({
         user: loggedIn.user,
         token: loggedIn.token,
        })
      );
      navigate("/home");
    }  
 } catch(error) {
    if (error.response.status === 400) {
       onSubmitProps.setErrors({ email: "Invalid email or password" });
    } 
 }
}
```

***The best solution is to create a global error handling in your application***

I suggest that you create an Alert component to display your http error messages, Formik and Yup are suitable more for form validation only not for axios error handling

Comment: I added the try catch block, still nothing shows